# $A \subseteq B$ and $|A \cup B| = x$. What's $|2^B|$ in terms of $x$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I'm pretty sure I translated my problem correctly in the title, but here's the English version:

A is a subset of B. There are $x$ total elements, all of which are either in A or B. I am trying to find the cardinality of the powerset of B where we can treat A as one term.

For example, if $A = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$, I can let $z = A$, and $B = \{z, f, g\}$. $|2^B|$ would contain $\{z\}$, $\{z, f\}$, $\{z, g\}$, and $\{z, f, g\}$, making the cardinality 4 (I'm omitting the emptyset).

Is there a way for me to generalize this for any $x$? I'm pretty sure I need another variable $y$ to represent the number of elements in either A or B, $0 \leq y \leq x$. I'm not sure what to do from here. I worked out a few specific cases but can't seem to find a general solution.

Comment: Hint: $A\cup B=B$...

Comment: Your example is confusing.  You state B={f,g}.  Where is A?

Comment: I also noticed that you assumed $A\subseteq B$ is the same thing as $A\in B$. They are not the same.

Comment: @herbsteinberg thanks for catching, just fixed

Comment: @DonThousand I don't think I correctly computed the powerset. But if A is a subset of B why wouldn't A also be an element of B. I know the converse is not true

Comment: @DonThousand can you expand on the hint? A union B is equal to what?

Comment: You need to stop and understand the meaning and difference between *subset* and *element of*.  Consider this... With $X = \{1,2,\{2\}\}$ you have $1\in X, \{1\}\not\in X, 2\in X, \{2\}\in X, 1\not\subset X, \{1\}\subset X, 2\not\subset X, \{2\}\subset X, \{\{2\}\}\subset X$.  Think of it as the "*depth*" is important.  There is a big difference between the object $1$ and the object $\{1\}$

Comment: A subset of a set is not an element of the set by definition.  The subset is an element of the power set.

Comment: Next, after your edit... you are talking about $B=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$ and $2^B$ containing $\{z\},\{z,f\},\{z,g\},\{z,f,g\}$... First... where did $z$ come from?  It is not an element of $B$... Next, what about $\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\dots,\{a,b\},\dots,\{a,g\},\dots,\{a,b,c\},\dots$  These are all also subsets of $B$ as you have written it...

Comment: Further still... you may not prove something holds in general by taking an explicit example of it and showing the property holds for that specific example.  It doesn't work that way.  Some properties might hold for the first several billion examples but then fail for some other example outside of the list of examples you checked

Comment: Finally... you should review your properties and definitions, specifically as it pertains to the power set.  It is well known that $|2^X|=2^{|X|}$, and you should review your properties of union... specifically as it pertains to if one set is a subset of the other... i.e. $A\subseteq B \implies A\cup B = B$

Comment: @JMoravitz i wrote in the question that $z = A$. I want to find the number of combinations of B that contain all the elements of A. Now that I think about it, this probably isn't appropriate for set theory, rather I might need to use combinations.

Comment: If the question in the title is the original intended question then there is by no means any requirement that the entirety of $A$ be included as a subset of the subsets you are counting.  If you are really wanting to count $\{X~:~X\subseteq (A\cup B)~,A\subseteq X\}$, that is a totally different problem.  In such a case you should be able to see that this set is in bijection with $2^{B\setminus A}$ and so has cardinality $2^{|B|-|A|}$ (*noting all of the relevant identities pertaining to the scenario*).  The set itself however is not able to be represented as some $2^K$, it is not a power set